# Bound items display as name of item type, instead of contents of each item

Tags: mvvm, maui

//My Model

```
public class BookInfo
    {
        public string BookName { get; set; }
        public string BookDescription { get; set; }
    }
```

//my View Model

```
 public ObservableCollection<BookInfo> Bookmodel { get; set; }

        public BookRepoInfo()
        {
            Bookmodel = new ObservableCollection<BookInfo> { //**is this correct way.**
                new BookInfo { BookName = "Object-Oriented Programming in C#", BookDescription = "Object-oriented programming is a programming paradigm based on the concept of objects" },
             ......
            };
        }
```

XAML page:

```
 <ContentPage.BindingContext>
   <local:BookRepoInfo />
 </ContentPage.BindingContext>
 <X:YList ItemsSource="{Binding Bookmodel}"></X:YList>
```

[image]

Load the list item using MVVM pattern

Comment: Whatever `YList` is, you need to supply a template that defines how each row should display

Comment: As @Jason said you need to define ItemTemplate or you can override ToString method of  your BookInfo class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `YList` is either a inheritance from `ListView` or `CollectionView`, you'll need to provide some sort of template which you want to apply to each cell of that list.

Right now what is happening is that it will just call the `ToString()` on the object that you put in.

Change your code to be something like:

```xml
<X:YList ItemsSource="{Binding Bookmodel}">
    <X:YList.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <VerticalStackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding BookName}"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding BookDescription}"/>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </X:YList.ItemTemplate>
</X:YList>
```

More information is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/populate-data?view=net-maui-7.0#define-item-appearance